# Objective-C: Uncast element of NSMutableArray returns unexpected type

Tags: ios, objective-c, casting, nsmutablearray, incompatibility

If am having trouble understanding the following. Consider the following code:

```
UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:@"car.png"];
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[array addObject:imageView];

UIImage *image2 = [imageView image];
UIImage *image3 = [[array objectAtIndex:0] image];
UIImage *image4 = [(UIImageView *) [array objectAtIndex:0] image];
```

The instructions with image2 and image4 work as expected. The line with image3 on the other hand displays an issue,

> Incompatible pointer types initializing 'UIImage *' with an expression
>   of type 'CIImage *'

I understand not type-casting the object retrieved from `NSMutableArray` might cause a problem. However, I have a hard time understanding why the compiler would think this expression to be of type `CIImage`.

If this question has been asked in more general terms, I apologize, I couldn't find it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's pull this apart:

```
UIImage *image3 = [[array objectAtIndex:0] image];
```

Just look at this part:

```
[array objectAtIndex:0]
```

Objective-C has no type information for the object returned from this method call, so it types it as an `id`. Now you are asking to send the `image` message to an `id`. But an `id` is not a typed object. What is Objective-C to make of this?

Basically, it has to guess *what message you are sending*. So it looks thru its known repertory of `image` methods, and just picks one. It knows of six such methods:

[image]

You meant the fourth one. But it happens that the compiler picks the first one, which returns a CIImage. So by your standards, it guessed "wrong". But you made it guess, and it had to guess *something*.

This is exactly the problem that the cast in your last example fixes:

```
UIImage *image4 = [(UIImageView *) [array objectAtIndex:0] image];
```

So, the moral: don't do what you did in the `image3` line. Do what you did in the `image4` line! You have type information that the compiler doesn't have: *tell* the compiler what you know.

(Observe that no harm is actually done by the way you wrote the code. The compiler warning is just that: a warning. In actual fact, when the `image` message is sent to the UIImageView, a UIImage will be returned and all will be well. But the compiler is warning you that it doesn't know this. By not casting you have given up all static typing and forced the compiler to take its hands off. The compiler doesn't know what will happen, so it warns you that this will have to be resolved *at runtime*. When you cast, you resolve the matter *at compile time*.)

Comment: Note that this whole issue would be absent if you had elected to use Swift, where arrays have element types. Alternatively, in modern Objective-C you could use a lightweight generic to tell the compiler that `array` consists of UIImageView elements.

Comment: First, thanks, awesome answer. I do use Swift, but with this particular project I need to use Obj-C because I have a lot of C math, I actually converted the whole project to Swift and had a terrible performance loss, but that's another story. Regarding your last paragraph: This is the reason why I was so confused, because (in an array with multiple ImageViews) `[array[0] setImage:[array[1] image]]` did not produce a compiler warning. Only when I used `[NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation([array[0] image])]` did the warning show up.